# How to inspect/parse/check PHP code to look for proper variable escaping

Tags: php, security

Is there a way to enforce (or verify) a naming convention in PHP scripts, where the type of string is denoted by the variable name.

With the types including things like:

- Plain text
- HTML escaped
- SQL escaped
- URL escaped

Where this is more so related to the security problems with incorrectly escaping variables.

---

So taking this overly simplistic example:

```
<?php

    $search = (isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : '');

    $output_html = '<p>Search for "' . htmlentities($search) . '"</p>';

//--------------------------------------------------

    $where_sql = '
        field LIKE "%' . $db->escape_like($search) . '%" AND
        deleted IS NULL';

    if (true) {
        $limit_sql = '50';
    } else {
        $limit_sql = '5, 10'; // From a pagnator?
    }

    $sql = 'SELECT name FROM table WHERE ' . $where_sql . ' LIMIT ' . $limit_sql;

    foreach ($db->fetch_all($sql) as $row) {
        $output_html .= '<p>Result ' . htmlentities($row['name']) . '</p>';
    }

//--------------------------------------------------

    $next_url = '/search/?q=' . urlencode($search) . '&page=2';

//--------------------------------------------------

    $image_id = intval(isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0);

    $image_path = '/www/images/' . safe_file_name($image_id) . '.jpg';

    $jpegtran_path = '/usr/bin/jpegtran';

    $jpegtran_cmd  = escapeshellcmd($jpegtran_path);
    $jpegtran_cmd .= ' -copy none -optimize -progressive';
    $jpegtran_cmd .= ' -outfile ' . escapeshellarg($image_path)
    $jpegtran_cmd .= ' ' . escapeshellarg($image_path);

    shell_exec($jpegtran_cmd);

?>

<p>Or possibly just printing out <?= htmlentities($variables) ?>.</p>
```

Notice how the variable names end in a type... such as _html, _sql, _url, _path, _cmd, _regexp, etc.

I realise that there is technology available to help with some of these issues (databases have ORMs, parameterised queries, etc... HTML can use templating languages, etc).

However, I was wondering if it was also possible to inspect the code (perhaps just in dev), and look for mistakes such as:

```
<?php

    $search = (isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : '');

    $output_html = '<p>Search for "' . $search . '"</p>'; // WARNING, XSS vulnerability!!!

?>
```

I have been wondering about [`token_get_all()`](https://www.php.net/token_get_all)... but looping though all the tokens is tricky:

```
<?php

    $output_html = '<p>' . htmlentities($count) . htmlentities($count == 1 ? ' items' : ' item') . '</p>';

?>
```

Resulting in something like the following, which will need to understand the nesting involved:

```
(
    [0] => (
            [0] => 372
            [1] => "<?php "
            [2] => 1
        )
    [1] => (
            [0] => 309
            [1] => "$output_html"
            [2] => 1
        )
    [2] => (
            [0] => 375
            [1] => " "
            [2] => 1
        )
    [3] => "="
    [4] => (
            [0] => 375
            [1] => " "
            [2] => 1
        )
    [5] => (
            [0] => 315
            [1] => "'<p>'"
            [2] => 1
        )
    [6] => (
            [0] => 375
            [1] => " "
            [2] => 1
        )
    [7] => "."
    [8] => (
            [0] => 375
            [1] => " "
            [2] => 1
        )
    [9] => (
            [0] => 307
            [1] => "htmlentities"
            [2] => 1
        )
    [10] => "("
    [11] => (
            [0] => 309
            [1] => "$count"
            [2] => 1
        )
    [12] => ")"
    [13] => (
            [0] => 375
            [1] => " "
            [2] => 1
        )
    [14] => "."
    [15] => (
            [0] => 375
            [1] => " "
            [2] => 1
        )
    [16] => (
            [0] => 307
            [1] => "htmlentities"
            [2] => 1
        )
    [17] => "("
    [18] => (
            [0] => 309
            [1] => "$count"
            [2] => 1
        )
    [19] => (
            [0] => 375
            [1] => " "
            [2] => 1
        )
    [20] => (
            [0] => 280
            [1] => "=="
            [2] => 1
        )
    [21] => (
            [0] => 375
            [1] => " "
            [2] => 1
        )
    [22] => (
            [0] => 305
            [1] => "1"
            [2] => 1
        )
    [23] => (
            [0] => 375
            [1] => " "
            [2] => 1
        )
    [24] => "?"
    [25] => (
            [0] => 375
            [1] => " "
            [2] => 1
        )
    [26] => (
            [0] => 315
            [1] => "' items'"
            [2] => 1
        )
    [27] => (
            [0] => 375
            [1] => " "
            [2] => 1
        )
    [28] => ":"
    [29] => (
            [0] => 375
            [1] => " "
            [2] => 1
        )
    [30] => (
            [0] => 315
            [1] => "' item'"
            [2] => 1
        )
    [31] => ")"
    [32] => (
            [0] => 375
            [1] => " "
            [2] => 1
        )
    [33] => "."
    [34] => (
            [0] => 375
            [1] => " "
            [2] => 1
        )
    [35] => (
            [0] => 315
            [1] => "'</p>'"
            [2] => 1
        )
    [36] => ";"
    [37] => (
            [0] => 375
            [1] => " "
            [2] => 1
        )
    [38] => (
            [0] => 374
            [1] => "?>"
            [2] => 1
        )
)
```

And unless I'm mistaken, most of the code linting / static analysis tools are just looking for things like "tabs vs the other one"... so completely missing the whole security aspect of this.

Comment: Try [a decent PHP parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) instead of just a tokenizer.

Comment: you may name your variables `$foo_type`, but most of the rest of the world isn't. analyzing variables names is generally pointless. they're just names. it's HOW you use the variables and their contents that matters.

Comment: Thanks @Gumbo, I'll have a look at the parser to see if it makes the output of token_get_all() earlier to understand (as it seems to be using it itself)... will report next week (when time allows).

Comment: Thanks @MarcB, but that is kind of the point in me asking... I want to enforce the naming convention programmatically, possibly with an SCM pre-commit hook (so they are used correctly, and identifiably)... unfortunately most devs only seem to care about types like integers, strings, etc (which is fair enough for performance reasons, but really not good enough for security).

Comment: don't try to recreate hungarian notation, or whatever other passing (and stupid) fads existed for dictating variable namings...

Comment: @MarcB, you might want to read up on Hungarian notation, there are 2 forms... unfortunately most devs only hear about the "stupid" int/str/float kind... the purpose of this naming convention (one I have been using for 15 years) is to identify the escaping of the variables contents (typically as strings), rather than their primitive types (i.e. I'm trying to address one of the main sources of security problems, still in the OWASP top 10, and which still has no proper solution for... says he knowing full well the ins/outs of several attempts, have you tried escaping LIKE parameters in SQL?)

Comment: I I have no trouble with something like `$escaped_foo = mysql_real_escape_string($foo)`. that's a purpose-based naming, not a content-based naming. `$str_string` is beyond moronic in its repetiveness.

Comment: @MarcB - At no point did I suggest _string... I've been using _sql to say it is escaped as SQL, _html when it's escaped as HTML, _url for something URL encoded, etc :-)